# Encontrar posición y coincidencia de un elemento en un array

Tags: php

Buenas quiero encontrar de un array su info guardada, que en este caso es un string y a su vez su posicion, pero no me estaria saliendo, por el momento hice esto:

```
<?php
 function buscarAnimal($animal){
  $a=$animal;
  $arry = array("Tortuga", 
           "Gallo",
           "Loro",
           "Puma");
  $posicion=0;
  $aencontrado[]=array();
  $longitudarray=sizeof($arry);


  for($i=0 ; $i<$longitudarray ; $i++){ /*recorro array*/

  if((isset($a)) && ($a==$arry[$i])){ /*1ero pregunto si existe ese valor y si es igual a uno de los elmentos del array*/
    $aencontrado[]=$arry[$i]; /*de ser asi le asigno ese valor al nuevo array*/
    $posicion=$i+1; /*y aca guardo su posicion*/

  } 

}

return $respuesta= "animal encontrado: ".$aencontrado[$posicion] . " , posicion : ".$posicion;/*esta es la linea 24*/
/*y por ultimo retorno la respuesta*/

 }
```

```html
<?php
include_once"mascotas.php";
?>
<!doctype hmtl>
<html>
<body>
 <?php
 
  $animal="Puma";
                $respuesta=buscarAnimal($animal);
                echo $respuesta;
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mascotas.php on line 24
>   mascota encontrada: , posicion : 0

En el if le agregue el isset para verificar si existe ese valor (hasta le asigne el valor por parametro en otra variable ya que creo q de ahi viene el problema pero no se xq esta mal), pero igual me devuelve lo mismo :/

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor, lo seleccionas y presionas ctrl + k para formatearlo y que sea visible

Answer (score 1):

Considero que puedes lograrlo de una forma mas ordenada partiendo de lo siguiente:

- Usamos el método `array_search()` de PHP el cual nos sirve para encontrar el elemento asignado y devolver la clave o posición asociada a ella
- Usamos el método `in_array()` también propio de PHP para verificar si el argumento pasado existe en el array declarado
- Declaramos 3 variables:

  - La variable posicion nos ayudará a almacenar el resultado que array_search nos devuelva
  - La variable resultado la usaremos para almacenar el posible mensaje retornado, que puede ser: no escribiste ningún animal, el valor existe en tal posicion o fallo si es que el animal pasado no existe
- Con un condicional simple primero evaluamos si la variable tiene algún valor asignado, si no es así devolvemos un mensaje y sino hacemos la evaluación primero con `in_array` para detectar si el elemento existe, en caso afirmativo ahora procede que evaluemos en que posición esta dicho elemento
- Posterior a lo anterior llenamos cada una de las variables con los valores correspondientes y por fuera de todo el condicional y antes de que cierre la función retornamos a la variable `$resultado`

Código

```
<?php

function buscarAnimal($animal){
  $animales = array("Tortuga", 
                    "Gallo",
                    "Loro",
                    "Puma",
                    );

    $resultado = "";
    $posicion = 0;

    if($animal == "") 
    {
        $resultado = "Debes ingresar un animal";
    } else {
        if(in_array($animal, $animales))
        {
            $posicion = array_search($animal, $animales);
            $resultado = " el elemento ".$animal." existe en la posición: ".$posicion;
        } else {
            $resultado = "Fallo";
        }
    }
    return $resultado;
}

echo buscarAnimal("Tortuga");
```

**Referencias**

- [método array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)
- [método in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

He tomado tu `array` y le he aplicado algunas pequeñas modificaciones para que soporte algo más de información respecto a los animales.

**mascotas.php**

```
<?php
 function buscarAnimal($find){
    //Definimos una respuesta por defecto para la función en caso que no se encuentre el animal
    $animal = false;
    $position = false;
    //Nuestro listado de animales en una matriz clave valor, donde el valor es otra matriz clave valor
    $animales = array(
        "tortuga" => ["dato1" => "tortuga dato 1" , "dato2" => "tortuga dato 2"], 
        "gallo" => ["dato1" => "gallo dato 1" , "dato2" => "gallo dato 2"], 
        "loro" => ["dato1" => "loro dato 1" , "dato2" => "loro dato 2"], 
        "puma" => ["dato1" => "puma dato 1" , "dato2" => "puma dato 2"]
    );
    // Isset valida que la variable exista y no sea nula, en este caso servirá para validad
    // que el elemento buscado (indice) exista en nuestra matriz de animales
    if(isset($animales[strtolower($find)])){
        $animal = $animales[strtolower($find)];
        // Utilizamos array_keys para obtener los nombres de las claves y transformarlo en un array
        // En el array devuelto por array_keys buscaremos la clave y nos devolverá la posición.
        $position = array_search(strtolower($find), array_keys($animales));
    }
    //Si el animal fue encontrado entregamos información, del contrario una respuesta por defecto
    if($animal && $position){
        $response = "Animal: {$find}, Posición: {$position}, Dato1: " . $animal['dato1'] . " Dato 2: " . $animal['dato2'];
    }else{
        $response = "No se encontró al animal";
    }
    return $response;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once "mascotas.php";
?>
<!doctype hmtl>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo 'Buscando al animal puma:<br/>';
        $animal="Puma";
        echo 'RESPUESTA:<br/>'; 
        echo buscarAnimal($animal);

        echo '<br/><br/>Buscando al animal gato:<br/>';
        $animal="gato";
        echo 'RESPUESTA:<br/>'; 
        echo buscarAnimal($animal);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```